# Retrieve the color definition in HTML

Tags: tables, color

I need to build a table of this type:

> STUFF | COLOR | PICTURE | COLOR DEFINITION

To retrieve the color definition, I tried to use `\extractcolorspecs` expecting that the third argument `{ color-cmd }` would allowed me to print what I needed. The problem is that I defined colors in HTML, while the command gives me RGB format in output. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mapblue}{HTML}{0000FF}%
\definecolor{maproyalblue}{HTML}{0088FF}%
\definecolor{mapskyblue}{HTML}{00CCFF}%
\definecolor{mapgreen}{HTML}{00CC00}%
\definecolor{mapdandelion}{HTML}{FFCC00}%
\definecolor{maporange}{HTML}{FF8800}%
\definecolor{mapred}{HTML}{FF0000}%

\newcommand{\colpic}[1]{\tikz \draw[#1,fill=#1,draw](0,0)circle(0.1cm);}
\newcommand{\colrow}[1]{#1 & \colpic{#1} & \extractcolorspecs{#1}{\model}{\mycolor}\mycolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsc{Relevance Interval}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsc{Color}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsc{Picture}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{ Color Definition}}\\
\midrule 
0 - 5 & \colrow{mapblue}\\
5 - 10 & \colrow{maproyalblue}\\
10 - 25 & \colrow{mapskyblue}\\
25 - 50 & \colrow{mapgreen}\\
50 - 100 & \colrow{mapdandelion}\\
100 - 200 & \colrow{maporange}\\
>200 & \colrow{mapred}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

and this is the output:
[image]

How is it possible to obtain the color definition in HTML?

Comment: There is also a command `\convertcolorspec` in the `xcolor` manual for conversion.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works. Should I write as answer the solution?

Comment: @percusse Please, expand your comment into an answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We can convert the stored version of the color definition (which is expressed in rgb) to HTML with

```
\newcommand{\colrow}[1]{%
  #1 & \colpic{#1} & \extractcolorspecs{#1}{\model}{\mycolor}%
    \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{HTML}\tmp\tmp
}
```

Also we can squeeze in the definitions of the commands like `\somecolorhtml` with some extra coding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,booktabs,xcolor}
\newcommand{\definemycolor}[2]{%
        \definecolor{#1}{HTML}{#2}%
        \expandafter\def\csname#1html\endcsname{#2\relax} %Which defines \colornamehtml
        }
\newcommand{\colpic}[1]{\tikz \draw[#1,fill=#1,draw](0,0)circle(0.1cm);}
\newcommand{\colrow}[1]{#1 & \colpic{#1} &\csname#1html\endcsname}
\definemycolor{mapblue}{0000FF}%
\definemycolor{maproyalblue}{0088FF}%
\definemycolor{mapskyblue}{00CCFF}%
\definemycolor{mapgreen}{00CC00}%
\definemycolor{mapdandelion}{FFCC00}%
\definemycolor{maporange}{FF8800}%
\definemycolor{mapred}{FF0000}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsc{Relevance Interval}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsc{Color}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsc{Picture}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{ Color Definition}}\\    \midrule 
0 - 5 & \colrow{mapblue}\\
5 - 10 & \colrow{maproyalblue}\\
10 - 25 & \colrow{mapskyblue}\\
25 - 50 & \colrow{mapgreen}\\
50 - 100 & \colrow{mapdandelion}\\
100 - 200 & \colrow{maporange}\\
>200 & \colrow{mapred}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
Since we defined the \verb|\colornamehtml| command versions of the colors,
\verb|\mapbluehtml| gives \textcolor{mapblue}{\mapbluehtml}  and 
\verb|\mapdandelionhtml| gives \textcolor{mapdandelion}{\mapdandelionhtml}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, I think a monospaced font would please more in the last column so replacing the `colrow` command with the following

```
\newcommand{\colrow}[1]{#1 & \colpic{#1} &\expandafter\texttt{\csname#1html\endcsname}}
```

would lead to

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question started circa 2012, and the original answers demonstrate the community's experts' prescience.

In 2016, Dr. Uwe Kern addressed the xcolor package (v2.12) (11 May 2016).

On p.23 of xcolor.pdf, https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor?lang=en , he talks about the package's "Color testing" features.  ¶ 2.6.4.

On p.31, there's a code snippet, here put into an MWE to give it working context.  With the macro input of the various ways colors are recognized, the output is tabular with rgb, cmyk, hsb, HTML, and gray. He recommends putting this macro in its own environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage[dvipsnames*, x11names, svgnames, hyperref]{xcolor}

\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{defaultcolor}{.}}

\begin{document}

\sffamily

\begin{testcolors}[rgb,cmyk,hsb,HTML,gray]
\testcolor{olive}
\testcolor{red!50!green}
\testcolor{-cyan!50!magenta}
\testcolor[cmyk]{0,0,1,0.5}
\testcolor[cmyk]{0,0,.5,.5}
\testcolor[rgb:cmyk]{0,0,.5,.5}
\end{testcolors}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In short, the analysis in the original answers is now, basically, a macro in the `xcolor` package.

Comment: Can you update your answer to something like `\HTMLcolour{<colour>}` that outputs the HTML colour specification as requested in the question?

Comment: @Werner Let me give it a relook and see.  What you're asking about is "output," while the title is asking about "retrieval."

Comment: @Werner By addressing this one, you've helped me spot an answer to a different issue. Back to the "output" question.

Comment: @Werner xcolor driver issue? It may be tomorrow. xcolor-material, kvoptions under test.

Comment: @Werner Started with bad copy/paste of percusse / Carlisle code. That solution generates the HTML "output." It's definitely the situation that mere "retrieval" of color command / spec info and "use" of it are two different things. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452299/170846   My "update" addressed the text of the question.  To understand that the "code" expands on the text of the question, we go from "mere retrieval" of color info to "use" of it.  The percusse / Carlisle code makes "use" of the retrieved info and produces the columnar HTML output. So, I may need a rephrasing of your ques.