# How to get actual values of colour theme colours in beamer?

Tags: beamer, color, themes

How would I go about finding the actual colour (like the RGB/HSV/etc) of a particular element in a given beamer colour theme (e.g., block title bg in orchid)?

I would like to use these colours in creating graphics with external programs. For example, I made a map in ArcGIS, and since it's quite a simple map, there's no reason not to choose colours which are consistent with the beamer theme I'm using.

From [In beamer use colors that are already defined in a given color scheme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8830/in-beamer-use-colors-that-are-already-defined-in-a-given-color-scheme?rq=1) and [Getting the color from a beamer theme?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33764/getting-the-color-from-a-beamer-theme), I know that you can directly call the colours within a LaTeX document, but I'm asking about getting colour values for use outside of LaTeX.

EDIT
Both answers below are great, thanks so much. I wasn't sure how to pick the accepted answer, so I just chose the one which seemed to accomplish the goal in fewer lines of code.

Comment: Why don't you just use a color picker software? You can find many of them for free on the internet.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I don't know if I get exactly the point, but my answer tries to make a table in which automatically you have some color definition just inserting the name (based on [Retrieve the color definition in HTML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51265/retrieve-the-color-definition-in-html) I defined).

With respect to Andrew's nice answer, mine just uses internal commands of `xcolor` to define macros able to extract the color value with a given format.

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\extractHTML}[1]{\extractcolorspecs{#1}{\model}{\mycolor} \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{HTML}\printcol \printcol}
\newcommand{\extractRGB}[1]{\extractcolorspecs{#1}{\model}{\mycolor} \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{RGB}\printcol \printcol}
\newcommand{\extractCMYK}[1]{\extractcolorspecs{#1}{\model}{\mycolor} \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{cmyk}\printcol \printcol}
\newcommand{\colrow}[1]{{\color{#1}#1} & \extractRGB{#1} & \extractCMYK{#1} & \extractHTML{#1}}

\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{fg=yellow}

% Create Color definition From Template: 
% #1 template name, 
% #2 foreground color name
% #3 background color name
\newcommand{\ccft}[3]{
\usebeamercolor{#1}
\definecolor{#2}{named}{fg}
\definecolor{#3}{named}{bg}
}

\ccft{block title}{myblock title fg}{myblock title bg}
\ccft{block body}{myblock body fg}{myblock body bg}
\ccft{block title alerted}{myblock title alerted fg}{myblock title alerted bg}
\ccft{palette secondary}{palette secondary fg}{palette secondary bg}


\usebeamercolor{block body}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Color definitions}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsc{Color}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{RGB}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{CMYK}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{HTML}}\\
\midrule 
\colrow{structure.fg}\\
\colrow{structure.bg}\\
\colrow{alerted text.fg}\\
\colrow{example text.fg}\\
\colrow{normal text.fg}\\
\colrow{myblock title fg}\\
\colrow{myblock title bg}\\
\colrow{myblock body fg}\\
\colrow{myblock body bg}\\
\colrow{myblock title alerted fg}\\
\colrow{myblock title alerted bg}\\
\colrow{palette secondary fg}\\
\colrow{palette secondary bg}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

> **Some explanation**

Some colors are immediately accessible, for example `structure.fg`, `alerted text.fg`, while for other like `palettes` or `blocks` is different. To cope with that, I referenced to Jake's answer in [On using beamer's colors in a Tikz picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60518/on-using-beamers-colors-in-a-tikz-picture) therefore a workaround is to declare first `\usebeamercolor{palette primary}`, for example, and later just use `bg`. That's the purpose of the command `\ccft` that defines two colors (color name provided by the second and third argument) starting from a template.

---

Here is an example that shows how to it's possible to retrieve the colors for all types of blocks assuming to adopt the *Frankfurt* theme and the *crane* color theme.

Blocks are characterized by a the color of the title (background `bg` and foreground `fg`) and the color of the body (again background `bg` and foreground `fg`).

The example could be seen as a sort of black box to detect blocks colors for any pair of *Beamer theme* and *Beamer color theme*: just copy the code in a new document `blocks_colors.tex` and change the apposite themes definition.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Theme characteristics - 
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{crane}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Commands -
\newcommand{\extractHTML}[1]{\extractcolorspecs{#1}{\model}{\mycolor} \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{HTML}\printcol \printcol}
\newcommand{\extractRGB}[1]{\extractcolorspecs{#1}{\model}{\mycolor} \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{RGB}\printcol \printcol}
\newcommand{\extractCMYK}[1]{\extractcolorspecs{#1}{\model}{\mycolor} \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{cmyk}\printcol \printcol}
\newcommand{\colrow}[1]{{\color{#1}#1} & \extractRGB{#1} & \extractCMYK{#1} & \extractHTML{#1}}

% Create Color definition From Template (both background and foreground colors): 
% #1 template name, 
% #2 foreground color name
% #3 background color name
\newcommand{\ccft}[3]{
\usebeamercolor{#1}
\definecolor{#2}{named}{fg}
\definecolor{#3}{named}{bg}
}

% Blocks color definition (background and foreground)
\ccft{block title}{block title fg}{block title bg}
\ccft{block body}{block body fg}{block body bg}
\ccft{block title alerted}{block title alerted fg}{block title alerted bg}
\ccft{block body alerted}{block body alerted fg}{block body alerted bg}
\ccft{block title example}{block title example fg}{block title example bg}
\ccft{block body example}{block body example fg}{block body example bg}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Block Color definitions - Crane color theme}
\scalebox{0.875}{
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textsc{Color}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{RGB}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{CMYK}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{HTML}}\\
\midrule 
\colrow{block title fg}\\
\colrow{block title bg}\\
\colrow{block body fg}\\
\colrow{block body bg}\\
\colrow{block title alerted fg}\\
\colrow{block title alerted bg}\\
\colrow{block body alerted fg}\\
\colrow{block body alerted bg}\\
\colrow{block title example fg}\\
\colrow{block title example bg}\\
\colrow{block body example fg}\\
\colrow{block body example bg}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{frame}    

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Title}
text
\end{block}
\begin{exampleblock}{Title}
text
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{alertblock}{Title}
text
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know that `xcolor` had these commands!  Otherwise I probably wouldn't have been hacking `colorinfo`.

Comment: Yes, in this case they are very useful. `:)` When I saw the question I immediately recall @percusse's answer that contained the major hint.

Answer (score 15):

There's a package for that ...

It's called [`colorinfo`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/colorinfo).  The idea is that one can define a colo[u]r using, say, `xcolor` (which is what `beamer` uses for its colour management, I think) and then use the `colorinfo` package to display the information about the colour.  However, I found that it didn't quite work as it should - it's missing some options for some drivers (I think `pdftex`) - so I modified it a bit.  The following code contains my modifications and an example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66465/86}

\usepackage{colorinfo}

\makeatletter
\def\ModColorInfo#1{%
  \begingroup
  \gdef\colorModel{}\gdef\colorValue{}%
  \@ifundefined{\string\color @#1}{}%
  {%
    \edef\@tempa{\csname\string\color @#1\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\CI@color@info\@tempa{} \CI@STOP
  }
  \endgroup
}
\def\CI@gobble#1\CI@STOP{}%
\let\CI@STOP=\relax

\renewcommand\CI@DriverInit{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{color}{%
    \@ifundefined{Gin@driver}{}{%
      \ifx\Gin@driver\@empty\else
        \filename@parse{\Gin@driver}
        \edef\colorDriver{\filename@base}
\@tempswatrue
\def\@tempa{dvips}
\ifx\@tempa\colorDriver
\else\def\@tempa{dvipdfm}
  \ifx\@tempa\colorDriver
  \else\def\@tempa{dvipsone}
    \ifx\@tempa\colorDriver
    \else\def\@tempa{pctex32}
      \ifx\@tempa\colorDriver
      \else\def\@tempa{xetex}
        \ifx\@tempa\colorDriver
        \else\@tempswafalse
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
\if@tempswa%                            --- dvips family ---
  \def\CI@color@info##1 {%
    \gdef\colorModel{##1}%
    \csname CI@dvips@\colorModel\endcsname
  }
  \newcommand*\CI@dvips@rgb{}
  \def\CI@dvips@rgb##1 ##2 ##3 {%
    \gdef\colorValue{##1,##2,##3}%
  }
  \newcommand*\CI@dvips@gray{}
  \def\CI@dvips@gray##1 {%
    \gdef\colorValue{##1}%
  }
  \newcommand*\CI@dvips@cmyk{}
  \def\CI@dvips@cmyk##1 ##2 ##3 ##4 {%
    \gdef\colorValue{##1,##2,##3,##4}%
  }
\else
  \def\@tempa{pdftex}
  \ifx\@tempa\colorDriver%              --- pdfTeX ---
    \providecommand*\@gobblefive[5]{}
    \providecommand*\@gobblesix[6]{}
    \def\CI@color@info##1 ##2 ##3 ##4 {%
      \def\@tempa{##4}%
      \def\@tempb{rg}%
      \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%   RGB
        \gdef\colorModel{rgb}\gdef\colorValue{##1,##2,##3}%
        \let\@tempb\CI@gobble
      \else
        \def\@tempb{G}%
        \ifx\@tempa\@tempb% GRAY
          \gdef\colorModel{gray}\gdef\colorValue{##1}%
          \let\@tempb\relax
        \else%              CMYK
          \gdef\colorModel{cmyk}\gdef\colorValue{##1,##2,##3,##4}%
          \let\@tempb\CI@gobble
        \fi
      \fi
      \@tempb
    }
  \else
    \def\@tempa{vtex}
    \ifx\@tempa\colorDriver%            --- VTeX ---
      \def\CI@color@info##1##2##3##4##5##6##7##8{%
        \def\@tempa{##2}\def\@tempb{"}%
        \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
          \gdef\colorModel{rgb}%
         \CI@normalize{\number"##3##4,\number"##5##6,\number"##7##8}%
           {\colorValue}\let\@tempb\relax
        \else
          \gdef\colorModel{cmyk}%
          \gdef\colorValue{\number"##3##4,\number"##5##6,\number"##7##8}%
          \let\@tempb\CI@vtex@cmyk%
        \fi
        \@tempb
      }
      \newcommand*\CI@vtex@cmyk{}
      \def\CI@vtex@cmyk##1##2{%
        \CI@normalize{\colorValue,\number"##1##2}{\colorValue}
      }
      \newcommand*\CI@normalize[2]{%
        \begingroup
          \def\@tempb{}\@tempswafalse
          \@for\@tempa:=##1\do{%
            \if@tempswa\edef\@tempb{\@tempb,}\else\@tempswatrue\fi
            \@tempdima=\@tempa\p@\divide\@tempdima by\@cclv\relax
            \edef\@tempb{\@tempb\strip@pt\@tempdima}}
          \xdef##2{\@tempb}
        \endgroup
      }
    \else
      \def\@tempa{textures}
      \ifx\@tempa\colorDriver%          --- textures ---
        \def\colorInfo##1{%
          \def\colorModel{}\def\colorValue{}%
          \@ifundefined{\string\color @##1}{}%
          {%
            \typeout{Not yet implemented...}
          }
        }
      \else
        \def\@tempa{tcidvi}
        \ifx\@tempa\colorDriver%        --- tcidvi ---
          \def\colorInfo##1{%
            \def\colorModel{}\def\colorValue{}%
            \@ifundefined{\string\color @##1}{}%
            {%
              \typeout{Not yet implemented...}
            }
          }
        \else
          \def\@tempa{truetex}
          \ifx\@tempa\colorDriver% --- truetex ---
            \def\colorInfo##1{%
              \def\colorModel{}\def\colorValue{}%
              \@ifundefined{\string\color @##1}{}%
              {%
                \typeout{Not yet implemented...}
              }
            }
          \else
            \def\@tempa{pctexps}
            \ifx\@tempa\colorDriver%    --- pctexps ---
              \def\colorInfo##1{%
                \def\colorModel{}\def\colorValue{}%
                \@ifundefined{\string\color @##1}{}%
                {%
                  \typeout{Not yet implemented...}
                }
              }
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
      \fi
    }%  \@ifundefined{Gin@driver}
  }{}%  \@ifpackageloaded{color}
}%      \CI@DriverInit
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A Colour Test}

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\alert{alert\ModColorInfo{.}} & \colorValue \\
\structure{structure\ModColorInfo{.}} & \colorValue \\
normal\ModColorInfo{.} & \colorValue
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Color info package with beamer colours]

Things to note: the command `\ModColorInfo{<colour>}` doesn't display anything itself, it stores its information in various macros.  This means you could write the information out to a file instead of the document which may be of more use.  Also, more information is available (such as the colour model).  Finally, the *current* colour in `beamer` is set to `.` so that's a simple way to find out what colour a particular element is.