# Change color scheme for example box in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, themes

I've already slightly adopted the colorscheme
of my Frankfurt themed beamer class with:

```
% Define my settings
\definecolor{mygreen}{cmyk}{0.82,0.11,1,0.25}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.8}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=mygreen}
```

Due to the settings of the structure-color to "mygreen" also the color for
the block is set to green similar to the exampleblock. Thus I want to change
the color of the exampleblock to blue (like the default non_modified block in Frankfurt)
or yellow (like in color scheme crane

[image]

I tried: `\setbeamercolor{exampleblock}{fg=blue}`
which has no effect :(

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The right keys to modify the `exampleblock` environment are:

- `block title example` for the title;
- `block body example` for the body of the block.

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
% Define my settings
\definecolor{mygreen}{cmyk}{0.82,0.11,1,0.25}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.8}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=mygreen}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=blue!50,
bg= blue!10}
\setbeamercolor*{block body example}{fg= blue,
bg= blue!5}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}
\begin{block}{Block title}
Hello
\end{block}
\begin{exampleblock}{ExampleBlock title}
Hello
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great. There are just two questions related to that: 1) Is there a list of all keys whose color can be changed? E.g I also need to change to colors of the itemize points in the example box. 2) Where can I extract the colors of predefined themes e.g. the above mentioned yellows of crane?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a list, but you find them along the [`beameruserguide`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). For what concern the color extraction, you could have a look to [How to get actual values of colour theme colours in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66465/how-to-get-actual-values-of-colour-theme-colours-in-beamer/66475#66475).

Comment: @Johannes: I've updated my answer [How to get actual values of colour theme colours in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66465/how-to-get-actual-values-of-colour-theme-colours-in-beamer#66475) in order to provide an example of blocks colors for the _Frankfurt_ theme and the _crane_ color theme.