# How to change the colour of the proof block

Tags: beamer

I just want to change the colour of the proof block so that it is a different colour from the theorem block.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.5cm,text margin right=1.5cm}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}

\title{My Presentation}
\subtitle{Using Beamer}
\author{Joe Bloggs}
\institute{University of ShareLaTeX}
\date{\today}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Characterisation of nilpotent groups}

\begin{theorem}
let $G$ be a group. Suppose that $H_{1}$, $H_{2}$, $K_{1}$  and  $K_{2}$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $H_{1} \subseteq H_{2}$ and $K_{1} \subseteq K_{2}$. Then $[H_{1},K_{1}]\leq [H_{2},K_{2}]$. 
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Suppose $[H_{1},K_{1}]$ is generated by $[h,k]$ where $h\in H_{1}     \;\text{and}\; k\in K_{1}$. Now since each of these generators are in    $[H_{2},K_{2}]$, the proof follows.
\end{proof}
```

Comment: And what is a proof block in this context? As always on this site, please provide a minimal example. Then at least we know a little about what we have to work with

Comment: I am using warsaw theme and the theorem and proof block are both in blue. I want to change just the proof block to a different colour

Comment: Have you read this post ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73163/change-color-scheme-for-example-box-in-beamer

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\addtobeamertemplate{proof begin}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=red!50!white}%
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=red, bg=red!30!white}%
}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=orange!50!white}%
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=orange, bg=orange!30!white}%
}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{qed symbol}{%
    \color{red}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem}[My theorem]
        A theorem.
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}[My proof]
        A proof.
    \end{proof}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]