# How to get beamercolor for block?

Tags: beamer, color

Suppose I have a block like this:

```
\begin{block}{My awesome block}
It really is awesome! It has a header and a body, both areas filled with fancy colors!
\end{block}
```

I want to use the background color of the block's body (that is, the area of the block, not the text within the block) OUTSIDE the block, because it's such a nice one. I know I can get the beamer color of any element by

```
\usebeamercolor[bg]{block}
```

however, using this I get white for the background and black for the foreground...which are probably the colors for the text within the block, but not the colors of the block structure itself.

Comment: Have a look to `block body` or `block title` template.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. But how can I use the block body background color outside of a block?

Comment: You can exploit [How to get actual values of colour theme colours in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66465/13304): after calling the `\ccft{template}{x fg}{x bg}` command you will have the two colors `x fg` and `x bg` to be used in, say `\textcolor{x fg}{text}`.

Comment: That's sweet, thanks! Care to make an answer out of it?

Comment: If that solved the problem, do you mind if we close this question as duplicate of the other one?

Comment: No, not at all!