# Is there a way to access the Beamer background color?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have some Tikz-drawings in my beamer presentation and my background color is slightly off-white (it doesn't stress the eye as much as pure white does) but I still want some drawings to be "transparent".

Is there a way to access the beamer background color as set by

`\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blanchedalmond!12}`

such that I would be able to write `\node[fill=\beamerBackgroundColor, ...]`?

Comment: Yes, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66475/194703.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beamer manual says

[image]

This suggests that you can use

```
\usebeamercolor{background canvas}
\node[fill=bg] at (4,0) {from beamer};
```

i.e. after invoking

```
\usebeamercolor{background canvas}
```

the color named `bg` is the background color. Indeed,

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=BlanchedAlmond!12}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Beamer colors in Ti\emph{k}Z}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue] (-2,-1) rectangle (6,2);
\node[fill=BlanchedAlmond!12]{by hand};
\usebeamercolor{background canvas}
\node[fill=bg] at (4,0) {from beamer};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since this color is hard to distinguish from the background, here is another test with `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}`.

[image]

If you wish to get the actual color specifications, you may consult [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66465/how-to-get-actual-values-of-colour-theme-colours-in-beamer?noredirect=1&lq=1).